How to disable Trim Duplicates on the search result on SharePoint 2019?
Users reported that SharePoint 2019 site search doesn't return all items. I found it is the TrimDuplicates that eliminates the result. I could not find where to change the setting on the site so when search on the site all items are returned no matter if they are duplicates. Thanks

When I add a search result webpart and edit the query I have a settings tab where I can disable duplicates

When I use the newer contentbysearch webpart this option is not available.

In SharePoint 2019, the TrimDuplicates setting for search results isn't exposed directly through the SharePoint site's UI.
You can customize it by using a custom query with the TrimDuplicates=false parameter, either programmatically or via a custom search experience using web parts.
